# JQuery animating border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this html code

```
<nav id="mainNav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>        
    </ul>
</nav>
```

It has the css style of this

```
    #mainNav { display:block; padding:5px; }
    #mainNav ul { display:block; list-style-type:none; width:500px; border-collapse:collapse; }
    #mainNav li { display:inline-block; width:100px; height:66px; text-align:center; padding-top:10px; float:left; background-color:gray; cursor:pointer; border-bottom:0px solid red; }
    #mainNav a { color:white; text-decoration:none; text-transform:capitalize; }
    #mainNav a.aHover { color:red; }
```

And attached to this is the JQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#mainNav li').mouseover(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    $(this).animate({
    "border-bottom-width":"+=5px"
    },{ queue: false, duration: 500 }, function() {
    el.css('border-bottom-width', '5px');   
    });
    $(this).children('a').addClass('aHover');
});
$('#mainNav li').mouseout(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    $(this).animate({
    "border-bottom-width":"-=5px"
    },{ queue: false, duration: 500 }, function() {
    el.css('border-bottom-width', '0px');   
    });
    $(this).children('a').removeClass('aHover');
});
});
```

Now what I want it to do is either, fade in the border colour to red and fade it out, or as written in the code, expand the border to a max of 5px on hover then deflate the border back to 0px.

Question is, as you can see I try to change the class of the LI element at the end of the animation to make sure the border goes to its max or min width, but that doesn't work, why?

How would you fade in and out the border colour?

Comment: `"border-bottom-width":"+=5px"`, shouldn't have `px`. Make it `"border-bottom-width": "+=5"`

Comment: You probably want to use mouseenter and mouseleave, or the hoverIntent plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/dEK9A/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mainNav li').hover(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
            "border-bottom-width": "5px"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });
        $(this).children('a').addClass('aHover');
    }, function() {
        var el = $(this);
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
            "border-bottom-width": "0px"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });
        $(this).children('a').removeClass('aHover');
    });
});
```

Changed,

1. `mouseover` event to `mouseenter` as it is more appropriate in your case
2. Changed `mouseenter/mouseleave` to `hover`
3. Changed `+=5px`, `-=5px` to `5px` and `0px`.
4. Added `.stop(true, true)` to make sure the animation is completed and the queue is cleared.

Comment: Excellent however, now when you mouse over the a tag within the LI element it thinks the mouse as left, so how can you maintain the border while hovering over the a tag?